# Change design item of GridView, how? - Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, gridview

I want to change a design of me item in GridView.

Now is:

[image: SCREENSHOT]

I want this item in square shape not like it is now in rectangle.
Also, the IMG (from the screenshot) i want to have above 'Name' and every textview at the center. Is it possible? Here is my XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/md_brown_100"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/credit_wallet"
        android:text="@string/hi"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/md_brown_700"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
    <com.justfashion.Logo

        android:text="Fashion Wallet"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/md_brown_700"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />




    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/list_offer_item_container"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:textColor="#48899f"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsizeearncredit_title"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtdesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="#80869c"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsizeearncredit_desc"
                android:text="This is a description of the offer and this is just a demo to show off 3 lines stacking correctly on top of each other"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/list_offer_badge_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/list_offer_item_container"
                android:textColor="@color/md_amber_700"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text=""/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgcreditcompany"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/txtname"
              android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:layout_height="42dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nextArrow"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:tint="@color/md_grey_300"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:padding="@dimen/two" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried a lot of combination and don't works. Please help me guys! Thanks!

## EDIT

The IMG from the screenshot is

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgcreditcompany"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/txtname"
              android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:layout_height="42dp" />
```

In the code above